# PHP Session Variable Array

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Hi I'm trying to understand session variables, in particular using them with arrays. In the example code below, the user enters a letter and I want to add that submission to a session variable so that the next time the user submits a letter I don't lose the previous entry.

So if the user enters 'e' the array displays 'e', and if the user then picks 's' then the array will now display 'e' and 's'. This is my first experiment with PHP and sessions are proving a little difficult to wrap my head around. Can anyone help me understand how to go about getting the result I want, or where I have gone wrong in the code below? Many thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();
function example()
{
$_SESSION['lettersGuessed'] = array();
$userLetter = $_GET['input'];
array_push($_SESSION['lettersGuessed'],$userLetter);
print_r($_SESSION['lettersGuessed']);
}


if (strlen($_GET['input'])==1) {
  if (ctype_lower($_GET['input'])) 
    {
        echo "The user-submitted letter is lowercase.<br>";
        example();
    } 

  else 
    {
        echo "Invalid submission<br>";
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="get">
<input name="input" value="Enter a letter!" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it out without array_push in a more simple way

There is a simple change in example function.

Following is complete code

```
<?php
session_start();

function example() {
    $userLetter = $_GET['input'];
    $_SESSION['lettersGuessed'][] = $userLetter;    
    print_r($_SESSION['lettersGuessed']);
}

if (strlen($_GET['input']) == 1) {
    if (ctype_lower($_GET['input'])) {
        echo "The user-submitted letter is lowercase.<br>";
        example();
    } else {
        echo "Invalid submission<br>";
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input name="input" value="Enter a letter!" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

?>
```

Comment: This is great thanks, helps me understand a great deal better

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your line in the beginning of `example()` resets the session variable to a blank array every time the function is called.

Update your `example()` function as follows:

```
function example()
{
    $_SESSION['lettersGuessed'][] = $_GET['input'];
    print_r($_SESSION['lettersGuessed']);
}
```

Thankfully, PHP is loosely-typed, so you don't have to manually define `lettersGuessed` as an array. Simply using `[]` afterwards will cause it to be handled as an array, and then using the `=` assignment operator will push `$_GET['input']` into it.

Comment: Hi BenM, thanks for trying to help me out, I've tried your code and I'm still having the same problem of the contents of the array being overwritten every time the user enters a new letter, any other ideas?

Comment: I tried this code on my server and it works fine > http://ben-major.co.uk/labs/stack-overflow/test.php

Comment: The example on your server works fine for me as well, but when I copy/paste the example function you've listed here it doesn't work for me oddly. I think I understand the nature of my problem now though, so thank you very much for the help

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked out for you. You might like to accept the answer in case it helped. Rather than accepting an identical answer posted an hour later...